# What is the best to use to describe styles for application content?

Tags: react-native

I have been creating application in React Native. The goal of the application is to have content that can be changed without updating the app. I understand that the two best solutions are either Firebase or some other API call at every application start to get new content. Now I would just like to know if there are any recommended way to style content beside my three current solutions:

- Styling content with markdown and then parsing it in application
- Styling content with html and then parsing it in application
- Or having a standard content object so that all the content is packed the same way and then showing right text/media on correct place with correct style

I am open to any other styling solutions for content and would like to know what is the best way. I also already have a server responding to API call that returns new content, the biggest problem is styling.

Comment: using a pre-processor such as SCSS which can take variables as input could be a solution https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-sass-transformer